# How to convert the BLOB value for the features geometry of type st_geometry kept in ArcGIS databse on Oracle

Tags: shapefile, enterprise-geodatabase, geometry, st-geometry

I am using ArcGIS Oracle database and I am trying to access feature geometry points as string. But the problem is that the points are kept as blobs and I can't convert to meaningful string.

```
select  sde.ST_AsText(a.SHAPE) 
from AKBIS_GEO.A236 a
```

About query returns response like below:

```
    ORA-28575: unable to open RPC connection to external procedure agent
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_SHAPELIB_PKG", line 67
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_OPERATORS", line 67
28575. 00000 -  "unable to open RPC connection to external procedure agent"
*Cause:    Initialization of a network connection to the extproc agent did
           not succeed. This problem can be caused by network problems,
           incorrect listener configuration, or incorrect transfer code.
*Action:   Check listener configuration in LISTENER.ORA and TNSNAMES.ORA, or
           check Oracle Names Server.
```

When we try this query:

```
select  a.SHAPE.points
from AKBIS_GEO.A236 a
```

The text value corresponding to the blobs related to points shows as follows:
(which is not useful for me)

[image: view on SQL developer]

Comment: You don't need to decode the underlying binary if you [properly configure the instance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/configure-oracle-extproc.htm).

Comment: Also the table you are referencing is an sde table and doesn't contain all of any information. that is an a table  (from a&d, adds and deletes). you need to use arc to create xy fields and extract that coordinates to those fields.

Comment: @BradNesom I understand that ı only need to find a way to convert the blob value to a meanful string .

Comment: @Vince I have already configured the instances. but the situation is the same

Comment: If you're getting that error, then the instance is NOT configured correctly.

Comment: The problem statement "Convert the blob value to a meaningful string" makes the problem seem much harder than it really is. Part of the issue is that it's NOT a BLOB column -- it's an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY column.  If the EXTPROC were configured correctly, you could just "access the object column data".  Accessing the column data of the ADDs table without using versioning will get you into difficulty very quickly, so I recommend caution.

Comment: how can I access to st_geometry type fields. I can write a query like this :  select  a.SHAPE.points
from AKBIS_GEO.A236 a

Comment: You can either access POINTS off a binary ***or*** interact with SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, not both. You probably need to withdraw this question and rewrite it with the necessary information:  The version of ArcGIS in use.  The version of Oracle (all five digits in the release number).  The geometry storage type (SDEBINARY, SDELOB, SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, SDO_GEOMETRY).  Whether the table is versioned.  Please describe your **goal**, not the methodology you've decided to use. Right now you're changing the primary content of the question in the sixth comment.

Comment: my goal is access to all history of a feature that serviced by arcgis. I have a feature service that contains several layer. the service provide all layer default versions. I want to show all history of layer. what time changed? how many times changed? what time deleted? that all questins must be answered.